# 'Response' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

Tags: python, fastapi

I keep getting this error all the time after i log in and dont know why. Please help!

```
@app.post("/login")
def Login(response: Response,credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(HTTPBasic())):
    correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.username, "root")
    correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.password, "root")
    if (correct_username and correct_password):
        response.status_code = 302
        response.headers["Location"] = "/welcome"
        return response

@app.get("/welcome")
def welcome():
    return {"message": "Hello"}
```

When I try to login using /docs, after typing correct username and password I get server error from uvicorn:

```
File ".\main.py", line 82, in Login                                                                               
response.headers["Location"] = "/welcome"

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'headers'
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: Ok, i did what you asked i guess. As far as i'm concerned to redirect a page you are supposed to add a location header to html response. And I totally don't understand why am I getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the import? It should be `from fastapi import Response` i have a similar code snippet in my code and it works with this import and the current fastapi version

Comment: I did! I have compared my code with a dozen others with the same functionality and still didn't notice what's wrong here...

Comment: And are you using the latest fastapi version? Otherwise i would need to see the rest of main.py.